# How to check if referenced table is not empty?

Tags: mysql

For example, I have 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS master(
    master_id      INT          NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    master_name    VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(master_id)
) TYPE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET=UTF8;
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS slave(
    slave_id        INT          NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    slave_name      VARCHAR(15)  NOT NULL,
    master_id       INT
    PRIMARY KEY (slave_id), 
    FOREIGN KEY (master_id) REFERENCES master(master_id)
) TYPE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET=UTF8;
```

How can I check if the master table is connected to the slave table and then, if it is,  I want to know if slave is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the two tables are connected by doing a join.

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) as number_of_connections
  FROM master m
  INNER JOIN slave s ON (s.master_id = m.master_id)
UNION ALL
  SELECT COUNT(*) as rows_in_slave
  FROM slave s2
UNION ALL
  SELECT COUNT(*) as rows_in_master
  FROM master m2
```

This query will return exactly 3 rows, that will tell you the number of connections, whether the slave table is empty and whether the master table is empty respectively.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I quite understand your question, but I'll try to answer.  The master table must be 'connected' to the slave table if you created the slave table with the foreign key reference `FOREIGN KEY (master_id) REFERENCES master(master_id)`.

As for whether the slave table is empty: it's empty if this query returns a column with zero in it:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM slave
```